# How to get localized resource programmatically?

Tags: c#, silverlight, localization, windows-phone-8.1

I have very simple question, but I'm stuck to get an answer on it

I'm trying to make a localization for my windows phone 8.1 silverlight app. everything is ok when I use XAML like in sample:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

but I cant get it programmatically to display several formatted messages in one TextBox

I want to do it like this:

```
if (e.Error)
    txtMsg.Text = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationTitle"] as String;
else
    txtMsg.Text = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationTitle2"] as String;
```

but any of found methods in internet does not provide such opportunity

So the question is: how to get localized resource programmatically using current system culture?

Comment: As it's Silverlight, then maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20906600/2681948) will help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks! it was helpful link!

the only thing that i was missing was

```
using ProjectName.Resources;
```

after that i can use expression

```
string str = AppResources.ApplicationTitle;
```

and str will be localized!